# I got the SUM() for a column in the first row plus the aggregate "group by" result

Tags: sql

i'm working with the airplanes, carriers and flight data base from the stat-computing.org

there is a Flights table with flights numbers (TailNum) and distances (Distance) for every flight

the SQL query that i working with is below:

it is quite simple and works fine, except that i got the sum of the Distance for all the flights in the first result row, and only after, the grouped result by TailNum.
Why i got this first row with the total distance for all flights??

```
SELECT TailNum, SUM(Distance) AS totalDistance 
FROM Flights GROUP BY TailNum ORDER BY totalDistance DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Looks like there should be blank TailNum values

Comment: Thanks, @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, the expected output is the SUM by Distance aggregated by TailNum. How can i share the sample data?

Comment: @RaulMagdalenaCatala edit your question to put in `create table` and `insert into` statements so people can easily copy and paste them.